# Why do Bluetooth packet sniffing tutorials for Windows require an adapter?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, sniffing

My laptop can very clearly scan for and receive data from Bluetooth signals, yet every tutorial I've read online requires the use of an adapter.

e.g. https://hackaday.com/2021/03/23/a-crash-course-on-sniffing-bluetooth-low-energy/

Why is this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> My laptop can very clearly scan for and receive data from Bluetooth signals,

Emphasis on *data.* If I understand things correctly, your laptop doesn't have access to the actual control frames being sent and received, its Bluetooth adapter's firmware handles those. For example, if the laptop's OS wants to scan for devices, it can't just receive the individual beacons that other devices are sending; instead it has to *ask the adapter's firmware* to start an inquiry, then ask it again to return collected results.

(Contrast this to e.g. TCP/IP/Ethernet, where it's the OS that keeps track of all TCP ports, MAC addresses, and so on, with the Ethernet card doing nothing more but transmitting the packets.)

So the nRF52840 that is mentioned in those tutorials likely isn't a generic Bluetooth adapter (and is not recognized by the OS as one), but a special device that works more like a programmable radio which *does* allow the computer to send and receive raw Bluetooth frames.

I assume the situation is quite similar to how Wi-Fi actually involves quite a bit more than just sending Ethernet frames over radio – e.g. the real layer-2 headers are actually quite different from what you see in regular Wireshark – and many 802.11b/g/n Wi-Fi adapters did have a dedicated "monitor mode" that would reveal the real 802.11 frame headers, together with non-data frames such as beacons. (There are even lists of which Wi-Fi products are usable for monitoring, which ones support MAC address spoofing, which ones allow injecting custom frames, etc.)